# simple horizontal menu with active links

Tags: html, css, menu

I am unable to add the active tab color to the menu code, can any body help me in this regard. I have collected the css horizontal code from  form following  tutorial:

http://www.freemenu.info/2013/04/menu.html

Apart from the hover color, I want another color for the active page. Please help me.

```
#menu a{
   display: block; padding: 5px 10px; 
   width: 100px; border-right: 2px solid #ffffff; 
   text-decoration: none;  border-left: 10px solid #1958b7;  
   color: #fff; background: #2175bc;
   }
#menu a:hover{
   color: pink; background: #2586d7;   
   border-left: 10px solid #1c64d1; 
   }
```

How

Comment: create one class in css. then using jquery addClass change the color of the active class

Answer (score 0):

Create an active class for your links (just add the class to your :hover CSS):

```
#menu a:hover,
#menu a.active {
    ....
}
```

Now you you have links like: `<a href="#" class="active">Link</a>`

Was that the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with javascript/JQuery, ([API Reference](http://api.jquery.com)):

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    //Remove class for other menu items.
});
```

and then more CSS:

```
#menu a.selected{
   background: red; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used to do:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
```

change that active for all the pages. 
Then in my CSS:

```
.active{
  //Your code goes here
}
```